# Why monitor color is incorrectly rendered?

Tags: display, colors

My 10 year old monitor (Dell s2240L) recently started rendering some colors incorrectly. They are instead rendered in  black color. Are these dead pixels? What could be the reason behind this problem ?

[image]

Above pic taken with a mobile phone

**Edit 1:**

Pic with white background, the spots on the screen are dust I assume, I cannot wipe it off from outside.

[image]

Above pic taken with a mobile phone

**Edit 2:**

Display information from Windows

[image]

Comment: A dead pixel. would be show as a white pixel, not black pixel.

Comment: What is your colour depth set to?

Comment: Can you add photos with a pure white screen too?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Added pic with white background

Comment: @spikey_richie Its 8 bit, I added a screenshot in question

Comment: What type of cable are you using between the graphics card and the monitor?

Comment: @spikey_richie its a hdmi cable

Comment: A monitor that lasts for 10 years is pretty good, but it might be time to move on.

Comment: those black dots are an early sign of failure , Kinda wierd there's disturbances around specific shades but I had a old monitor that failed similarly, the layers in them LCD panel were delaminating

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Were you able to fix it ?

Comment: Delamination is final. If you move that colour palette, do the same colour blocks remain black?

Comment: @spikey_richie yes the same colors remain black, regardless of the position

Answer (score 1):

That's *not* a screen issue - a dead pixel is *always* dead, not just when you try to display a certain color.

My guess is that this is a graphic card problem, or maybe a software issue. Can you borrow another screen and try it (same issues - it's your computer for sure), or try *your* screen on some other laptop or PC.

Comment: I have tried it on two intel laptops and one amd laptop, the issue reamins the same